# Двумерный ArrayList

Tags: android

Как сделать двумерный массив из ArrayList и как получить 1(i) значение и 2(j) значение
Пример

```
ArrayList<String> one = new ArrayList<String>();
for(Element newsheader : newsheaders){ 
    Element One = newsheader.select("a[href]").first(); 
    one.add(One.text()+"\n");// 1 значение
    //one.add(One.attr("href")+"\n"); // 2значение
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Правильный вариант - хранить в `ArrayList<Element>`